# How to define Array in XML field - Joomla

Tags: php, xml, joomla, joomla3.0

I have try to define a array in media field name in joomla xml file.but it doesn't work.

[image: What i want]

```
<field name="s1img[]" label="Image 1" type="media" directory="Images" />      
<field name="imgSetting[]" type="text" default="" label="Image Setting" description="" size="60"/>

<field name="s1img[]" label="Image 2" type="media" directory="Images" />
<field name="imgSetting[]" type="text" default="" label="Image Setting" description="" size="60"/>

<field name="s1img[]" label="Image 3" type="media" directory="Images" />
<field name="imgSetting[]" type="text" default="" label="Image Setting" description="" size="60"/>
```

When i used this code it looks like this.

[image: Now it looks]

How I fix this??

Comment: exactly what you want? explain more.are you need multiple upload ajax

Comment: i want to 3 media fields and it name should be in array name `name="s1img[]"`  but i try to do it.. the last media field only show. how i fix it?

Comment: can i know, you have trying custom component ?

Comment: yes.. i'm try to make slide show module ..

Comment: nice.joomla  same name not allowed? so you can set different name and stored  folder of file name.

Comment: how i define the array name ?? I want to that all images paths in one array..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124290/discussion-between-josef-and-backslash).

Answer (score 0):

Proper escaping must be done in order to do this, so, for example, you should replace:

```
<field name="s1img[]" label="Image 1" type="media" directory="Images" />
```

With:

```
<field name="s1img][]" label="Image 1" type="media" directory="Images" />
```

You should do this for all your "array" fields.

Comment: i use this method.. but not working.. Same issue.. :(

Comment: i use joomla 3.6.0

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting correctly than you can try giving index value to fields as shown in below -

**XML CODE:**

```
<field name="s1img[0]" label="Image 1" type="media" directory="Images" />      
<field name="imgSetting[0]" type="text" default="" label="Image Setting 1" description="" size="60"/>

<field name="s1img[1]" label="Image 2" type="media" directory="Images" />
<field name="imgSetting[1]" type="text" default="" label="Image Setting 2" description="" size="60"/>

<field name="s1img[2]" label="Image 3" type="media" directory="Images" />
<field name="imgSetting[2]" type="text" default="" label="Image Setting 3" description="" size="60"/>
```

Than in view render these fields -

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('s1img[0]'); ?></div>
    <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('s1img[0]'); ?></div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('imgSetting[0]'); ?></div>
    <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('imgSetting[0]'); ?></div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('s1img[1]'); ?></div>
    <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('s1img[1]'); ?></div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('imgSetting[1]'); ?></div>
    <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('imgSetting[1]'); ?></div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('s1img[2]'); ?></div>
    <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('s1img[2]'); ?></div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('imgSetting[2]'); ?></div>
    <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('imgSetting[2]'); ?></div>
</div>
```